# Loop over variables that are named in an order

Tags: python

If we want to call some function by passing arguments that are variables named in some sequence x1, x2, x3,....

```
def helloWorld(a):
   some code
```

how to loop and pass them . instead of writing function call for each

```
helloWorld(x1)
helloWorld(x2)
helloWorld(x3)
....
```

maybe something like

```
for i in range(100):
   helloWorld(xi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: *(be careful when using eval)*

```
for i in range(100):
   helloWorld(eval("x" + str(i)))
```

Comment: Just note that `eval` is evil and should only be used as a last resort. There are almost always better approaches.

Comment: Many argue against using `eval` where possible, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/967621 . In the case of the OP, it is possible to avoid `eval` by refactoring the code and using better structures to store values (e.g., list or dict instead of individual variables).

Answer (score 4):

Just put the values in a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and iterate over it:

```py
for x in [x1, x2, x3]:
    helloWorld(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of naming the variables `x1, x2, x3, ...`, consider using a dictionary or, better, a list, to store these values. Then call the method like so (in this example, using a list):

```
lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
for x in lst:
    helloWorld(x)
```